# Unable to access ExtJS 7.5.0 sample application

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I recently got myself into ExtJS. Followed the 'Getting started with NPM' and run a fresh modern-app sample. While the sample does seem to run, I noticed the following error.

> i [ext]:  [ERR] [ERR] Error: spawn
> /home/mahas/projects/extjs/cool-universal-app/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/sencha
> EACCES     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (node:internal/child_process:282:19)     at onErrorNT
> (node:internal/child_process:477:16)     at processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

My browser endlessly loading the app and this warning appeared on my console

> <i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /

I have tried to wait several minutes just in case of Webpack actually bundling assets but the same warning appeared.

Comment: What is your `java` and `node` version?

Comment: I have the same mistake. How did you fix this error?

Comment: @PeterKoltai java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS and NodeJS v16.13.2

Answer (score 4):

The problem is solved simply by the command:

```
chmod 777 "/home/mahas/projects/extjs/cool-universal-app/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/sencha"
```

Answer (score 0):

Khusamov Sukhrob solution works.

Using `chmod 777 your_project_path/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/sencha` can make `npm run dev` work for your sencha app.

Alternatively, you can still use classic sencha cmd, `sencha app build development` and `sencha app watch`, to develop and start your sencha app.